# How do you prevent crawling from your web site?

Tags: iis, web-crawler

I am running a website on IIS with more than 1000 page links at pagination and I want to prevent others to crawl/steal these pages by running a crawler script and get the info page by page.

Is there any way to understand the request if it is a user request or being ran by a script? or maybe some filters for this on highest level before coming to request?

Comment: You can't "prevent", but see [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) (all of these questions are addresses on said site). Any crawler that is nice enough not to lie about itself should also honor such robot rules. Any "sensitive" or "private" material must *not* be accessible by unauthorized users.

Comment: @user2864740 - yes, nice crawlers will respect robots.txt, but it is unlikely one trying to grab the data from a particular site will respect any "please don't look there" suggestions.

Comment: is there anyway to bypass robots.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent automated crawling.

You can make it harder to automatically crawl your content, but if you allow users to see the content it can be automated (i.e. automating browser navigation is not hard and computer generally don't care to wait long time between requests).

One option is to require single "user" (either authenticated or not) to have some minimal delay between requests (i.e. 1-5 seconds). This way generic crawling will not be useful (require some "user id" in request and delay between requests), and one would have to write custom crawling code which is clearly more time intensive.

Note that writing special "crawler" for your site may be considered as "noble" action and significantly increase incentive to create one (i.e. check out "how to make Google maps available offline" questions).

Comment: can you please explain more about Google Map ? making them offline is a kind of cache crawling or sthg?

Comment: @Kubi - on "Google maps offline" - to take them offline you need at least tiles - so you need crawl site for that. While clearly against license agreement such request comes up often enough - so whoever implement a solution will gain some popularity points/get famous/whatever. As result more people would be willing to spend time implementing that particular crawling code than some random unknown site with no demand.